# How to create fields dynamically

Tags: python-polars

Is there any way to create fields dynamically?. I know there are some ways. But it will be better to know best approach in polars. For example I want to add 12 shifted columns to existing dataframe.(lag1, lag2, lag3...lagN) How to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the python language for that. Polars expressions are lazily evaluated, so you can create them anywhere, in a for loop, a function, list comprehension, you name it.

Below I give an example of dynamically created `lag` columns, one by calling a function, assigning to a variable and then using that variable. And one with a list comprehension.

```py
# some initial dataframe
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "a": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    "b": [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
})

# a function that returns a lazy evaluated expression
def lag(name: str, n: int) -> pl.Expr:
    return pl.col(name).shift(n).suffix(f"_lag_{n}")

# a lazy evaluated expression assigned to a variable
lag_foo = lag("a", 1)

out = df.select([
    lag_foo,
] + [lag("b", i) for i in range(5)]  # create exprs with a list comprehension
)

print(out)
```

This outputs:

```
shape: (5, 6)
┌─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ a_lag_1 ┆ b_lag_0 ┆ b_lag_1 ┆ b_lag_2 ┆ b_lag_3 ┆ b_lag_4 │
│ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     │
│ i64     ┆ i64     ┆ i64     ┆ i64     ┆ i64     ┆ i64     │
╞═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╡
│ null    ┆ 5       ┆ null    ┆ null    ┆ null    ┆ null    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1       ┆ 4       ┆ 5       ┆ null    ┆ null    ┆ null    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2       ┆ 3       ┆ 4       ┆ 5       ┆ null    ┆ null    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3       ┆ 2       ┆ 3       ┆ 4       ┆ 5       ┆ null    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4       ┆ 1       ┆ 2       ┆ 3       ┆ 4       ┆ 5       │
└─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┘
```